# In pgpool while using delete query inside postgresql function ,it is not deletingdata from all servers

Tags: database, postgresql, pgpool

I have created following function in pgpool .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function fun1(Id int)
RETURNS boolean as $executionStatus$
DECLARE

BEGIN
    DELETE FROM table1 where table1_id =  Id ; 
    DELETE from table2 where table2_id =  Id ;
    DELETE from table3 where table3_id =  Id ;
    RETURN true;
END;
$executionStatus$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I run following command inside the postgres shell of pgpool

```
select fun1(1);
```

It is deleted the data only from master. I tried again then it is deleted from different server.So replication fails in this case. But if i use delete queries separately then it is working fine.It is deleting data from all servers.

```
DELETE FROM table1 where table1_id =  1 ;DELETE from table2 where table2_id =  1 ;DELETE from table3 where table3_id =  1 ;
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found answer myself
In replication mode (replication_mode = on),the SELECT is load balanced and only one of the PostgreSQL
servers receives the command. Solution would be:

1) Add "/*REPLICATION*/" comment in front of the SELECT.

2) Add func1 to the black_function_list.